# Operation TimeOut when Trying to send a meesage to Telegram bot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telegram-bot

I have a Telegram Bot and its an Admin of a channel. I send a messages to it and it was working very well, but Suddenly it breaks and not working! It works on Local Server still but not on Host!
I use this Url:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot" + Token + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + message
```

Comment: what you means than say *I send messages to it*? you send messages in the channel? do you use any library?

Comment: also please show your getting updates method

Comment: I'd suggest you use this framework: [Here](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp)